# Open a local web page from Perl

Tags: perl, preferences

I'm writing a Perl script that creates HTML output and I would like to have it open in the user's preferred browser.  Is there a good way to do this?  I can't see a way of using `ShellExecute` since I don't have an `http:` address for it.

Comment: Is using Perl like PHP what you want to do? In that case you could look for CGI, FastCGI, ...

Comment: @black: Why would I use CGI?  I'm displaying a local `.html` file with a browser just like I might display a local `.docx` file with Word.

Comment: allright, sorry I misunderstood. However even if you don't have `http:` address, you may use `ShellExecute` on `file://path/to/file` (if the problem is the address...) sorry I'm not windows user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you saved your output to "../data/index.html",

```
$ret = system( 'start ..\data\index.html' );
```

should open the file in the default browser.

Added:

[Advice here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=151299):

```
my $filename = "/xyzzy.html";  #whatever
system("start file://$filename");
```

Comment: @Josh: No, because - as morungos wrote - a 'default browser' (user specified program to deal with .html files) is a window-ish concept. Your local file manager may store information about your preferences wrt .html showing; otherwise you'll have to check for installed browsers and/or let the user choose.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, this will not work. You would have to setup a web server, like [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) and configure it to execute your script. This wouldn't be a trivial task if you've never done it before.

Comment: I have set up web servers before, including Apache, but I don't see how that's relevant here.  I want to generate a file on one machine and view it on that same machine.  It's not being served to remote clients.

Comment: I misinterpreted your question. I didn't know your data was dumped to a file. I thought you wanted to essentially create an executable that rendered HTML (stdout) seamlessly to the user that executed the script.

Comment: That would be kind of nice, but impractical (as you pointed out).  I think it deserves a +1 even though it's not what I had in mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Windows, the easy option is to dump the data to a temporary file using `File::Temp` (making sure it has an extension .htm or .html, and that it isn't cleaned up immediately on script exit, so that the file remains, i.e, you probably want something like `File::Temp->new(UNLINK => 0, SUFFIX => '.htm')`). Then you ought to be able to use `Win32::FileOp`'s `ShellExecute` to open the file regularly. This does make all sorts of assumptions about file types being associated with file extensions, but then, that's how Windows tends to work.

Comment: The question is about that last part: how do I open the file in the user's browser (given a file location that I've written to) when I don't know what browsers the user has installed?  I wouldn't want to execute `firefox %tmp%\foo.html` if there's no Firefox on the machine.  Ideally it would use the default browser.

Comment: Just try `ShellExecute($tmp->filename());`, where $tmp is the temporary file object from `File::Temp` -- that ought to open the file as if you had double-clicked it. On Windows, that will typically open it in the browser.